# How can I write numpy arrays as high dynamic range images?

Tags: image, numpy, image-processing

I am doing some image deconvolution in Python, and the deconvolved image is produced in a numpy array with 3 axes: `x`, `y` and RGB. So a typical array has a shape of `3000 x 3000 x 3`.

I wish to output the result as an image file of some sort.   PNG, TIFF, JPEG or any other widely used format would be fine.

My problem is that the functions such as `imageio.imsave` all write the file with only 8 bits of precision per color plane.   I need more dynamic range. There is an "experimental" bits parameter for `imageio.imsave`, but it seems to have no effect for RGB images.

**Is there a way to output a numpy array as an RGB image with 16 or 32 bits of precision per color plane?**

Comment: Have you, I dunno, attempted to look it up?

Comment: Gosh, no!   I would never have thought of that.   Thanks for your extremely helpful response.

Comment: Well, you didn't share the results of your research, so I had to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/), which already uses NumPy arrays for images. For saving, there's the [`imwrite`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce) function:

> In general, only 8-bit single-channel or 3-channel (with 'BGR' channel order) images can be saved using this function, with these exceptions:
>
> - 16-bit unsigned (CV_16U) images can be saved in the case of PNG, JPEG 2000, and TIFF formats
> - 32-bit float (CV_32F) images can be saved in PFM, TIFF, OpenEXR, and Radiance HDR formats; 3-channel (CV_32FC3) TIFF images will be saved using the LogLuv high dynamic range encoding (4 bytes per pixel)

I did the following small test:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

image_8 = np.uint8(np.random.rand(300, 300, 3) * 255)
image_16 = np.uint16(np.random.rand(300, 300, 3) * 65535)
image_32 = np.float32(np.random.rand(300, 300, 3))

cv2.imwrite('image_8.png', image_8)
cv2.imwrite('image_16.png', image_16)
cv2.imwrite('image_32.exr', image_32)
```

I could open all images using GIMP, and the bit depths were all correctly set. I was NOT able to write and open (with GIMP) an 32-bit float TIFF, and I can't explain why that is. There are several [`ImwriteFlags`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga292d81be8d76901bff7988d18d2b42ac), but none seems to address TIFF saving with 32-bit float. Nevertheless, 32-bit float EXR worked.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks very much!   That works.   One odd note is that the order of the RGB planes in imageio is the opposite of the order in OpenCV.